# ORPOS transaction queue is getting stuck

Tags: opos

ORPOS transaction queue is getting stuck due to "the customer name that is read from the magnetic stripe of the card comes in as 50+ characters that looks like an encryption code

Answer (score 0):

The details you provide indicate the fault with the card and/or the validation system. But regarding the transaction queue thing, make sure the connection is robust because having the BO database or the store server offline leaves you getting transaction queued up at POS.